# Programmatic completion of keycloak required actions

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I'm looking for a way to complete programmatically a keycloak required action for a user in a spring boot app. The keycloak version is 21.0.1. In my case, I need to successfully complete the TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS action if a certain boolean flag has been set.